# Take picture using html 5 and js

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on "Take photo", I just get a black screen. I have been trying for 3 hours to solve this, but I have hit a dead end. I am able to chose a picture that is on the tablet, but I just can't take a new picture. My JS code looks like this:

```
function hasSelectedPhoto() {
var x = 0, y = 0, width = 150, height = 130;

var takePicture= document.querySelector("#take-picture"),  
    showPicture= document.querySelector("#show-picture");

if (takePicture&& showPicture) {
    takePicture.onchange = function (event) {
        var files = event.target.files, file;

        if (files && files.length > 0) {
            file = files[0];

            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var imageUrl = e.target.result, c = showPicture, context = c.getContext("2d"),
                imageObject = new Image();
                imageObject.onload = function () {
                    context.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
                    context.drawImage(imageObject, x, y, width, height);
                };
                imageObject.src = imageUrl;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    };
}
```

}

And html code:

```
<div id="uploadedImageDiv" style="margin-left: 10px; width:300px; float: left;">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NoteViewModel.ImageUpload)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NoteViewModel.ImageUpload, new { id="take-picture", type = "file", accept = "image/*" })                 
            <input type="button" id="cancelPicture" value="Annuller billede" style="visibility: hidden;" />  
            <button type="reset" id="resetUploadedImage" style="display: none"></button>        
        </div>

        <canvas id="show-picture" style="display: none; border: medium solid #cccccc; margin-top: -50px;" width="150" height="125">
        </canvas>
```

I know there is a bunch of js code, but I really hope someone might spot a bug in my code, that makes med unable to take a picture. I'm desperate

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the code that tries to take the photo? Where is that "Take photo" button you're mentioning?

Comment: I have edited my code, so you can see where the picture is taken. The text "Take photo" is one that the ipad bringes up when I click on the textbox for taking the picture

Comment: Then it looks like the problem is coming from the tablet, not the browser.

Comment: just saw your updated code, so I've deleted my answer as not relevant. my only advice would be, have you tried it on a different device? do you get any errors in console?

Comment: I have tried it on the ipad and windows 8 tablet. The win8 tablet doesn't give the possibility to take a picture, it only gives the possibilities select a picture fro the device storage. It does seem like it is my code

Comment: Why do people down vote this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use html2canvas jquery for taking snapshot of your screen.

for details you can refer [link](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html)

just download html2canvas.js and use it as following:

```
function takeSnapshot{
          var Obj = $("# id of you div or element");
          html2canvas($(Obj), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                  theCanvas = canvas;
                  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                  var captureImage=  canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""),
                  document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }
}
```

Comment: I have just tried it on a mobile phone, and here it works. Could it be something with Camera permission that needs to be set on the tablet, in order to be able to use the camera online? I have tried searching about this, but found nothing